# Filipino on Schengen visa requesting UK tourist visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

A Filipino national being in Schengen area with valid tourist visa (visa C) can request a tourist visa to visit UK (standard UK visa) from a Schengen country without having to move back to his country ?

Answer (score 3):

To quote from [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy):

> You can make applications for a visit visa or EEA family permit in any visa application centre, British diplomatic mission or consular post overseas where entry clearance applications are accepted.
>
> You should be present legally in the country or territory you’re applying from.

Visa application centres are listed [here](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre).